# How can i set the maximumRetryAttempt for aws lambda in the cloudformation lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a serverless project created throught visual studio and i'm looking for setting the maximumRetryAttempt of a specific lambda in the cloudformation template.
I saw EventInvokeConfig, however the lambda function name is generated automatically and different from each environment. I am wondering if there is an aws specific parameter to get a lambda function name?

```
  "EventInvokeConfig": {
  "Type" : "AWS::Lambda::EventInvokeConfig",
  "Properties" : {
      "FunctionName" : "???",
      "MaximumRetryAttempts" : 0,
      "Qualifier" : "$LATEST"
    }
}
```

Here is my serverless template

```
{
 "AWSTemplateFormatVersion":"2010-09-09",
 "Transform":"AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31",
 "Description":"An AWS Serverless Application that uses the ASP.NET Core framework running in Amazon Lambda.",
 "Resources":{
    "MyFunctionLambda":{
       "Type":"AWS::Serverless::Function",
       "Properties":{
          "Handler":"MyPlatformServerless::MyPlatformServerless.Lambdas.MyFunctionLambda::FunctionHandler",
          "Runtime":"dotnetcore2.1",
          "CodeUri":"",
          "Description":"Default function",
          "MemorySize":512,
          "Timeout":60,
          "Role":null
       }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Is the lambda function created as part of this cloudformation template?

Comment: @franklinsijo yes the lambda function is created in the cloudformation template

Comment: Please update the post with complete template!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of the `Ref` instrinsic function. For the resource of type `AWS::Serverless::Function` the returned value is the name of the function.

This can be referenced in other resources defined in the template. For `EventInvokeConfig`, the template would look like

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion":"2010-09-09",
    "Transform":"AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31",
    "Description":"An AWS Serverless Application that uses the ASP.NET Core framework running in Amazon Lambda.",
    "Resources":{
        "MyFunctionLambda":{
            "Type":"AWS::Serverless::Function",
            "Properties":{
                "Handler":"MyPlatformServerless::MyPlatformServerless.Lambdas.MyFunctionLambda::FunctionHandler",
                "Runtime":"dotnetcore2.1",
                "CodeUri":"",
                "Description":"Default function",
                "MemorySize":512,
                "Timeout":60,
                "Role":null
            }
        },
        "EventInvokeConfig": {
            "Type" : "AWS::Lambda::EventInvokeConfig",
            "Properties" : {
                "FunctionName" : { "Ref" : MyFunctionLambda },
                "MaximumRetryAttempts" : 0,
                "Qualifier" : "$LATEST"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your issue might have resolved already but you can improve the code. As you're using Serverless (SAM) you can directly specify the `EventInvokeConfig` in the lambda resource properties and no need of another resource creation. Please find the below snippet:

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion":"2010-09-09",
    "Transform":"AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31",
    "Description":"An AWS Serverless Application that uses the ASP.NET Core framework running in Amazon Lambda.",
    "Resources":{
        "MyFunctionLambda":{
            "Type":"AWS::Serverless::Function",
            "Properties":{
                "Handler":"MyPlatformServerless::MyPlatformServerless.Lambdas.MyFunctionLambda::FunctionHandler",
                "Runtime":"dotnetcore2.1",
                "CodeUri":"",
                "Description":"Default function",
                "MemorySize":512,
                "Timeout":60,
                "Role":null,
                "EventInvokeConfig": {
                    "MaximumRetryAttempts" : 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also specify other attributes like `DestinationConfig` and `MaximumEventAgeInSeconds` in the `EventInvokeConfig` object.

> References:
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-function-eventinvokeconfiguration.html

Comment: `MaximumEventAgeInSeconds` can also be set within `EventInvokeConfig`.  It has a minimum value of `60`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include the MaximumRetryAttempts inline with your function definition you can, but you must include a reference to the FunctionName within the EventInvokeConfig (similar to the accepted answer) as it is a required field.

Additionally, the docs don't mention, but this will default to 2 if absent.

See the docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-eventinvokeconfig.html

In my case I generate my function names with parameters at build.

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion":"2010-09-09",
    "Transform":"AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31",
    "Description":"An AWS Serverless Application that uses the ASP.NET Core framework running in Amazon Lambda.",
    "Resources":{
        "MyFunctionLambda":{
            "Type":"AWS::Serverless::Function",
            "Properties":{
              "FunctionName": "DistinctFunctionName" 
              "Handler": "MyPlatformServerless::MyPlatformServerless.Lambdas.MyFunctionLambda::FunctionHandler",
                "Runtime":"dotnetcore2.1",
                "CodeUri":"",
                "Description":"Default function",
                "MemorySize":512,
                "Timeout":60,
                "Role":null,
                "EventInvokeConfig": {
                    "FunctionName" : "DistinctFunctionName"
                    "MaximumRetryAttempts" : 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```